# Question on primitive ring

Tags: noncommutative-algebra

I wanted to show that the ring $R=M_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a not primitive.

Here is what I did.

Suppose for contradiction it is primitive. Then there is a faithful and irreducible  $R-$ module $M$.

Let $$0\neq x\in M$$

Then from the irreduciblity of $M$, $$Rx=M$$

Define a module homomorphism $$\phi:R\rightarrow M, r\mapsto rx$$

Then  $$ker(\phi)=ann_{R}(M)={0}$$
(here is one of my doubt) by the faithfulness of the module. Moreover $\phi$ is subjective. Therefore $\phi$ is an isomorphism. But we know that $R$ is not simple module as an $R$ module.Let its the non trivial sub module be given by $V$. Therefore contradiction( as $\phi(V)$ is a non trivial sub module of $M$, which was claimed as irreducible).

Is my argument correct. Or is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $M_2(\mathbb Z)$ is primitive. Being right primitive is a Morita invariant property, so $\mathbb Z$ is also primitive. But a commutative primitive ring is a field, so $\mathbb Z$ is not primitive, a contradiction.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the same explanation I gave the user [on a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2499551/29335), so they must be interested in something more low power. We might actually have to explain what a maximal right ideal of the matrix ring looks like.

Comment: Is the property of Morita invariant also applicable for showing primness. That means can I say $R$ is prime if and only if $M_{n}(R)$ is prime?

Comment: @wow Yes, being a prime ring is a Morita invariant property, and $R$ is prime iff $M_n(R)$ is. $M_n(\mathbb Z)$ and $\mathbb Z$ are indeed both prime rings.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't work, because you could apply the same argument to any ring.

The kernel of $\phi$ is the annihilator of $x$, which is not generally the same as the annihilator of $Rx$ when $R$ is not commutative.

For commutative rings the argument works to prove that primitive is the same as simple, that is, a commutative ring is primitive if and only if it is a field.